# igraph error long vectors not supported yet when trying to create adjacency matrix

Tags: r, matrix, igraph, adjacency-matrix, network-analysis

I'm trying to perform a social network analysis in R, and I'm having some troubles with creating adjacency matrices from very large matrices using the igraph package. One of the main matrices is 10998555876 elements large (82 Gb) - created from a dataset with 176881 rows.

The error I get when running:

```
adjacency_matrix <- graph.adjacency(one_mode_matrix, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE, diag = TRUE)
```

is as follows:

```
Error in graph.adjacency.dense(adjmatrix, mode = mode, weighted = weighted, : 
long vectors not supported yet: ../../src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:519
```

The data is two-mode, so I've had to transpose it to get the one-mode matrix with the units I'm interested in. The code used before to create the matrix is:

```
graph <- graph.data.frame(data, directed = FALSE) # Making a graph object from the dataframe.
types <- bipartite.mapping(graph)$type 
matrix <- as_incidence_matrix(graph, types = type) # Creating a  two-mode matrix.

one_mode_matrix <- tcrossprod(matrix) # Transposing to get one-mode matrix.
diag(matrix) <- 0 
mode(matrix) <- "numeric" 

adjacency_matrix <- graph.adjacency(one_mode_matrix, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE, diag = FALSE) # This is where things break down.
```

Having done some research, e.g. in this thread https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/255 , it looks like a problem in R base. It seems to me (without being an expert on these things) that igraph is trying to create an object in a format that R cannot handle because it is too big(?) Does anybody know how to handle this issue? Perhaps there are other packages for creating adjacency matrices that would do a better job on a large matrix?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to anybody who might be interested:**

I discovered that igraph can handle sparse matrices. Convert the matrix to a sparse matrix using the Matrix package like so:

```
sparse_matrix <- as(one_mode_matrix, "sparseMatrix")
```

Then make it into a graph object like this:

```
g <- graph_from_adjacency(sparse_matrix)
```

And ravel in all the functionality igraph has to offer.